# Sublime Text 2 Run C++11 Code

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext2

I have the following code in Sublime Text 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s("some string");
    if (s.begin() != s.end())   // make sure s is not empty
    {
        auto it = s.begin();    // it denotes the first character in s
        *it = toupper(*it);     // make that character uppercase
    }

    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

I can **build** C++11 code in Sublime by pressing ctrl-B as I changed my `C++.sublime-build` file to

```
"cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
```

But I want to **build and run** the code at the same and I usually do this with **ctrl-shift-B**.  I get an error msg from the compiler which I received before editing my sublime-build file:

```
/home/michael/src/c++-primer/pointers.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/michael/src/c++-primer/pointers.cpp:12:14: error: ‘it’ does not name a type
         auto it = s.begin();    // it denotes the first character in s
              ^
/home/michael/src/c++-primer/pointers.cpp:13:10: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
         *it = toupper(*it);     // make that character uppercase
```

This suggests to me that when I press **ctrl-shift-B**, it is not using the sublime-build file I edited.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I figured it out.  You need to add the flag in the "Variants" section of the build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
```

}