# Cannot predetermine values for a vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I'm using sublime text for C++ and, for some reason, I am not able to predetermine values for a vector.

```cpp
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Whenever I do such a thing, I get this error:

```
'std::vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
                     ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using?

Comment: Perhaps [c++ - Sublime Text 2 Run C++11 Code - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480152/sublime-text-2-run-c11-code) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sublime Text 2 Run C++11 Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480152/sublime-text-2-run-c11-code)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this : std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5}; ?

Comment: It's only available if you use C++11 or superior

Comment: I tried that before it just got me different error

Answer (score 0):

This directly answers your question:

```
std::vector<int> v;
    
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

To be more generic, [checkout](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/):

```
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> v (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

Finally print the results with an iterator:

```
 std::vector<int>::iterator vi;
 for(vi = v.begin(); vi != v.end(); ++vi)
     std::cout << *vi;
```

One more option would be to `push_back()` every different value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, please

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout 
#include <numeric> // std::iota 
#include <vector> // std::vector
  
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<int> v(6);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1); 
  
    std::cout << "Elements are :"; 
    for (auto i : v) 
        std::cout << ' ' << i; 
    std::cout << '\n'; 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Elements are : 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: thanks but what if I wanted unrelated numbers like 6 2 8 9